# Login in WebUser return FALSE

Tags: php, yii

**Yii::app()->user->login** return **FALSE**.

How can this return FALSE and why?

Code:

```
public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }


    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        $r2 = Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
  MyLog::log("res r: ".var_export($r2, true));
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

IMAGE CODE: http://clip2net.com/s/5fmhNR

Comment: It can't. Please include more information for context, such as the full method body and maybe some controller context as well!

Comment: looks like you have some code outside the if statement. Did u check if any of them returns false?

Comment: doesn't checking the value of `this->_identity->errorCode` helps?

Comment: use an echo within the second `if` statement and check if it enters the if block

Comment: @kevin this expression return true. There it's ok.

Comment: What does the image code have to do with this?

Comment: This is standart class of Yii.

Comment: http://clip2net.com/s/5fmzxT

Comment: Ok does it successfully log in ??

Comment: @Ninad Yes, succefull. But the code that is above - Yii::app()->user->login return false. I don't know why.

Comment: Can u post your content from Yii::app()->user and $_SESSION:

Comment: @Ninad Content: http://clip2net.com/s/5fngWX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CWebUser->login() does not return anything

```
Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity, $duration)
```

It will return null

Comment: I can not login. Even if the username and password are correct, there is no error, but also no authorization.

Comment: previously u said that u logged in successfully ??

Comment: Function login() by LoginFrom return TRUE. Login and password is right. After logging site redirects to the home page, but not authenticated (

Comment: What do u mean by not authenticated what error are u getting ??

Comment: There is no error, just does not authorize. It feels that the sessions are not working

Comment: Yes, it's most likely your sessions in some way. I've seen this behavior when the tmp folder where sessions are stored was not writeable (you can specify with savePath if you're using the normal session setup) or with DB errors